# animate css (margin-top: XY) with jquery on anchor points

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make a margin, from css, animate and push UL list down when an anchor point reaches the top of the page. Also, this code kind of works, but it does not work at all in responsive.

```js
$(".testolino a").click(function(evn) {
  evn.preventDefault();
  $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash);
});

var aChildren = $(".testolino li").children();
var aArray = []; // create the empty aArray
for (var i = 0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {
  var aChild = aChildren[i];
  var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
  aArray.push(ahref);
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var docHeight = $(document).height();

  for (var i = 0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
    var theID = aArray[i];
    var theID1 = (i) * (-130) + 'px';
    var divPos = $(theID).offset().top;
    var divHeight = $(theID).height();
    if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
      $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("nav-active");
      $(".listau").animate({
        "margin-top": theID1
      }, {
        duration: 100
      });
    } else {
      $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
    }
  }

  if (windowPos + windowHeight == docHeight) {
    if (!$(".testolino li:last-child a").hasClass("nav-active")) {
      var navActiveCurrent = $(".nav-active").attr("href");
      $("a[href='" + navActiveCurrent + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
      $(".testolino li:last-child a").addClass("nav-active");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: white;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}
#content {
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 24px;
}
/* navigation */

.testolino {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 1024px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.testolino.stick {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
.testolino ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 130px;
}
.testolino li {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.testolino li a {
  color: rgb(243, 46, 152);
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 99px;
}
.testolino li a:hover {
  color: rgb(243, 46, 152);
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.nav-active {
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.listau {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.visedugme {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
  color: #ec0080;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.visedugme:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #ec0080 !important;
}
.ssection {
  padding: 100px 0 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ec0080;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="nav-anchor"></div>
      <div class="testolino">
        <ul class="listau">
          <li><a href="#home">PPC KAMPANJA</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#about">ANALIZA</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#services">SEO</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#blog">MOBILNI INTERNET</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">SMM</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#last">SEGMENTACIJA</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /sidebar -->
    <div id="content">
      <section class="ssection" id="home">
        <a href="#" class="visedugme hvr-overline-from-center">
        </a>
      </section>
      <section class="ssection" id="about">
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="visedugme hvr-overline-from-center">
        </a>
      </section>
      <section class="ssection" id="services">
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="visedugme hvr-overline-from-center">
        </a>
      </section>
      <section class="ssection" id="blog">
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="visedugme hvr-overline-from-center">
        </a>
      </section>
      <section class="ssection" id="contact">
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="visedugme hvr-overline-from-center">
        </a>
      </section>
      <section class="ssection" id="last">
        <a href="#" class="visedugme hvr-overline-from-center">
        </a>
      </section>
    </div>
    <!-- /#content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</div>
```

Comment: Include your HTML and CSS to the question.

Comment: hope i did this right this is my firs question here